# Read Fixed Width File with dask.dataframe

Tags: python, dask

Does dask have a function for reading and parsing fixed width files like pandas read_fwf?  If not has that been a requested feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no dask equivalent of `read_fwf`, but there is `read_table`, which can sometimes read the same files (you may need specify some keyword arguments). `read_fwf` could be added, but no issue request has been made yet. If your problem is not resolved by `read_table`, please [file an issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues).

Answer (score 1):

Since December 2018, this feature is added to Dask.
Let's have a look to the merge: [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/4316).